# Is there a way to tell css-grid an item is essentially absolutely positioned, while staying in its grid cells?

Tags: css, grid, vuejs2

I am playing around with a sort of pseudo masonry layout using grid.
So far it is doing exactly what I want... with one exception.

I want to be able to filter out certain types of bricks and bring them back. Now, I can do that just fine, except I want to animate the filtering because I have found users don't notice items are being filtered out. Likely, due to change blindness.

I have linked a jsfiddle that implements everything I am looking for, except that tiles don't fade out when they are removed

The code I provide in the jsfiddle is Vue.js, but that isn't super important. all you need to know is that whatever CSS properties need to be applied should probably happen in the class "cell-leave-active".

The class that allows bricks to transition into new positions is "cell-move".

What I am hoping to find is some css-grid property that will allow the same behaviour I have, but it keeps the bricks in position while they fade, but **doesn't** stop other bricks from moving into their position as they fade.

maybe Something along the lines of, "keep this element inside its current grid position but don't influence the position of other elements in the grid"... if such a thing exists. However, even that may not be the solution... because that would likely cause elements which are animating out to all overlap one another... So, I am kind of at a loss!

[jsfiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/liefswanson/pmvzh5wL/6/)

```
.cell-leave-active {
  position: absolute;
  visibility: hidden;
}
```

This class as it is, allows other bricks to move into the position of bricks that are currently being filtered out.

If we remove `position: absolute;` and `visibility: hidden;`

We get the fading behaviour I want, but other bricks do not transition into their new positions, until after the bricks have completely faded. In fact they don't transition at all, because their transitions are over

So, if you filter out some bricks and click the reset button I provide in the fiddle... That is the animation I want, but in reverse, as tiles get filtered out.

P.S. The way I am getting the elements to fit in the grid the way they are is by use of a dynamically created style, which you can find in the html.

```
grid-row-end : span <some dynamically determined int>
```

Edit:
I have considered having an entire second grid underneath, and performing the animations I don't get from this method on the underneath second grid... but I really don't want to do that. I would rather the elements didn't animate exactly the way I want, rather than double the number of bricks I am rendering and applying JavaScript to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two separated issues here: One is how to keep the cells in place when using `position: absolute` and the other one is how to fade them out.

#### Keeping cells in place with position: absolute

To fix the former, you need to set some additional properties on all the excluded cells, apart from `position: absolute`, and `position: relative` on the parent:

```
.container {
    position: relative;
}

.cell-leave-active {
    position: absolute;
    visibility: hidden;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

Then, you also need to specify the [`grid-area`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/grid-area) **on each of them**:

For example, for a cell that sits in the top-right corner and that takes one column and 2 rows, you would have `grid-area: 1 / 1 / 2 / 3`.

You can quickly test this solution on a single cell on your code using the Inspector, but here's a simpler example:

```css
.grid {
  position: relative;
  display: grid;
  grid-gap: 4px;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 50px);
  grid-template-rows: repeat(2, 50px);
  justify-content: center;
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
  
.grid > li {
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.grid > li:hover {
  background: cyan;
}

#bigOne {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  grid-row: 1 / 2;
  grid-column: 1 / 3;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background: rgba(255, 0, 0, .25);
  pointer-events: none;  
}
```

```html
<ul class="grid">
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  
  <li id="bigOne"></li>  
</ul>
```

#### ✨ Fading out the cells

The second issue is that [`visibility`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/visibility) is not an animatable property, so you should be using [`opacity`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/opacity) instead.

Then, you could add [`pointer-events: none`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/pointer-events) to prevent mouse events (click, hover, ...) on them while they are disappearing.

Comment: hmmm, that didn't seem to work. the box still disappears, just as before.

likely because visibility: hidden;

If I take that off, it takes up the whole div.

also you meant grid-area; 1/1/4/1 right?

This would also require me to know the position of every brick in the layout right?

Oops you updated, let me look at it again sorry!

Comment: Yes, those are two separated issues. First, you need to keep them in place when using `position: absolute` and then you should use `opacity: 0` for the fading-out and probably `pointer-events: none` to prevent clicks on them while they are fading out.

Comment: Alright, thanks! If I get something going given your advice I will give your answer "accepted". Currently still playing around with it. It may not be feasible to know the position of each brick, but I will keep playing with it.

It also isn't quite acting as I expect even on the one brick I set in the inspector.

Comment: Take a look at [`HTMLElement.offsetLeft`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/offsetLeft),  [`HTMLElement.offsetTop`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/offsetTop),  [`HTMLElement.offsetWidth`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/offsetWidth) and  [`HTMLElement.offsetHeight`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/offsetHeight). That might be usefull to know to which position each cell has gone after using auto-placement.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/liefswanson/pmvzh5wL/7/

Not entirely done yet, but if you set the grid-area: on the first cell, that seems to be working!

I will play with it more... Thanks very much. As I said if I can manage to set the grid-area dynamically you will definitely get the accepted. :-)

Comment: It didn't technically get me all the way there, as I can't easily get the row and column the cell gets placed in by default, but this did get me most of the way there. Accepted as it did technically answer the question as posed. :-)

Thanks again.